# How to Get All String Before First " ABC" in PHP

Tags: php

I want to get all the string before first " **Jobs**"

For Example If i have below string

"**This is Organization Name Jobs | Latest Jobs - MySite**"

then i should get "**This is Organization Name**"

I wrote below code but its not working fine for me

```
<?php
echo strtok("This is Organization Name Jobs | Latest Jobs - MySite", " Jobs");
?>
```

Comment: From the manual about [strtok()](http://php.net/manual/en/function.strtok.php) _"The string will be tokenized when any one of the characters in the argument is found."_ which means that it will use _any_ of the characters in the token as delimiter (in this case, it uses `s`), not the complete string.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

In your specific case - use [`strstr`](http://php.net/manual/en/function.strstr.php) with third parameter as `true`:

```
echo strstr("This is Organization Name Jobs | Latest Jobs - MySite", " Jobs", true);
```

Answer (score 0):

You can also use the explode() function, like this:

```
$string = "This is Organization Name Jobs | Latest Jobs - MySite";
$var = explode(' Jobs ', $string);
echo $var[0];
```